# how to use "require" to add a prop url for React bootstrap Card img src

Tags: react-native

I am building a Card in React with React Bootstrap

```
    const  ScreenImage = props =>(
<div>
<Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
     <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.url} /> 
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>milestone</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Build Milestone to identify major work structures needed to achieve the goal.
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
</div>
 );
```

I want to pass the url as a prop

I can do this

```
<div><ScreenImage url='https://robohash.org/2?set=set2&size=200x200' />
</div>
```

or this

```
<div><ScreenImage url={require('../../images/milestone.png')} />
</div>
```

both work and I can see the image

but when I define `var one = '../../images/milestone.png')`

and try to pass it as `url={require(one)}`

I get an error:
Error: Cannot find module '../../images/milestone.png'

when I  try: `url=one`

I get an empty image.

if I use

```
var one = 'https://robohash.org/2?set=set2&size=200x200';
```

then  `url=one` works.

I tried to put the required in the card

```
 <Card.Img variant="top" src={required({props.url)} />
```

but that would not compile.

Comment: Try `var one=require('../../images/milestone.png');` and then use `url=one`. (this is kind of strange but require needs a string only we cannot inject it that way)

Comment: <ScreenImage  url = one /> would not compile,

Comment: <ScreenImage  url = {one} />  does. not work

Comment: <ScreenImage  {url = one} />  does not compile